# getResourceAsStream returning null for Image src

Tags: java, javafx

This is one of my first JavaFX Project and I have a problem. in the class CardController, the "getClass().getResourceAsStream(book.getImageSrc())" returns null and i do not know why.

```
public class CardController {

    @FXML
    private HBox box;

    @FXML
    private Label authorName;

    @FXML
    private Label bookName;

    @FXML
    private ImageView bookImage;
    private String[] colors = {"B9E5FF", "BDB2FE", "FB9AA8", "FF5056"};
    public void setData(Book book){

        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(book.getImageSrc())); //here is where i have the problem

        bookImage.setImage(image);
        bookName.setText(book.getName());
        authorName.setText(book.getAuthor());

        box.setStyle("fx-background-color: #"+ colors[(int)(Math.random()*colors.length)] +";" +
                " -fx-background-radius: 15;" +
                "-fx-effect: dropShadow(three-pass-box, rgba (0,0,0,0,,1), 10, 0, 0, 10);");
    }

}
```

```
public class Book {

    private String name;
    private String ImageSrc;
    private String author;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setImageSrc(String imageSrc) {
        ImageSrc = imageSrc;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getImageSrc() {
        return ImageSrc;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
}
```

```
public class HelloController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private HBox cardLayout;

    @FXML
    private GridPane bookContainer;
    private List<Book> recentlyAdded;
    private List<Book> recommended;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        recentlyAdded = new ArrayList<>(recentlyAdded());
        recommended = new ArrayList<>(books());

        int column =0;
        int row = 1;

        try {

            for (Book value: recentlyAdded) {

                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
                fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("card.fxml"));
                HBox cardBox = fxmlLoader.load();
                CardController cardController = fxmlLoader.getController();
                cardController.setData(value);
                cardLayout.getChildren().add(cardBox);
            }

            for(Book book: recommended){

                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
                fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("book.fxml"));
                VBox bookBox = fxmlLoader.load();
                BookController bookController = fxmlLoader.getController();
                bookController.setData(book);

                if(column ==6){
                    column =0;
                    ++row;

                }

                bookContainer.add(bookBox, column++, row);
                GridPane.setMargin(bookBox, new Insets(10));

            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private List<Book> recentlyAdded(){

        List<Book> ls = new ArrayList<>();

        Book book = new Book();
        book.setName("RICH DAD \n POOR DAD");
        book.setImageSrc("richDadPoorDad.jpeg");
        book.setAuthor("Robert T.Kiyosaki");
        ls.add(book);
        return ls;
    }

    private List<Book> books(){

        List<Book> ls = new ArrayList<>();

        Book book = new Book();
        book.setName("RICH DAD \n POOR DAD");
        book.setImageSrc("richDadPoorDad.jpeg");
        book.setAuthor("Robert T.Kiyosaki");
        ls.add(book);
        return ls;
    }
}
```

Comment: So is there an image called `richDadPoorDad.jpeg` in the same package as the `CardController` class at runtime?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but this color specification `rgba (0,0,0,0,,1)` is syntactically wrong.  See the [CSS reference](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) for valid color styles.

Comment: I would assume that `Book` instances are "dynamic". That is to say, books are loaded from an external source, such as an application database or a web API. If that's the case, then it does not make sense for the book's (cover?) image to be a _resource_, because you can't add resources at run-time. You most likely should simply be using `new Image(book.getImageSrc())`, where the "image source" string is a file or http(s) URI.

Comment: Otherwise, this is probably a duplicate of [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531317/6395627).